# Excel adding production time and dividing by total profit

Tags: excel-formula

I am wanting to add how long each step of a job takes and divide that total by the job's profit to adjust my pricing.

I have cells A1:D1 formatted to hh:mm 
I have tried:

```
| B   | C   | D   | E           |
|-----|-----|-----|-------------|
| :15 | :30 | :15 | =SUM(B1:D1) |
```

My result in `E1`: **0**

I then tried:

```
| B   | C  | D   | E           |
|-----|----|-----|-------------|
| .25 | .5 | .25 | =SUM(B1:D1) |
```

My Result in `E1`: **0**
- I did switch my format here to "general" for the cells `B1:D1` and got the correct answer, but it drives me nuts I can't use time!?

I then thought - I do know how to subtract the difference between two times for a time sheet (how many hours did I work between *3:00 AM* and *4:15 AM* so I did that and got the correct answer: 1 hour in `E1`, and what I'm really in need of is how much I'm making per hour.  
I then divide my profit in `G1` by my result in `E1`:  `=G1/E1`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjFpF.jpg)

And I'm getting *$853.93* per hour.  .... where am I going wrong on this?

My `F` & `G` columns are formatted as *Accounting*

Thanks in advance.  What is it about Excel and time?  If someone knows of a good tutorial on understanding how Excel sees time, that might help too.  I've looked on SO and google.  I read all the posts SO suggested when I entered my question title and went though several before posting my question.

Thanks again,
Alika

Comment: How did you get an hour _between 3:00 AM and 4:15 AM_ - that's an hour and 15?  Try multiplying E2 by 1440 (number of minutes in a day).  1 = 1 day or 24 hours, 0.5 = half day or 12 hours.

Comment: @Alika Thompson type in a cell 01:00 and you will see that formatting will change to custom (hh:mm) or type 1:00 AM and formatting will change to custom (H:mm AM/PM).Then you can you sum or subtract formula

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet (reputation below 50). However, I believe I have something valuable to add :)

1. If you want to calculate time in Excel learn about how it is represented in Excel (it is represented as a number): [this article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) covers the subject.
2. Either you made a typo in your post or you have a circular reference:

> my result in E1:  =G1/E1

3. Learn about format: [h]:mm:ss
   [image]